# The meaning of "en" in "Mais si je ne formule plus ma prière, en connaîtrez-vous moins pour cela le délirant souhait de mon cœur"

Tags: sens, pronoms

The question is on *en* as highlighted in this passage from the 'Alissa's Journal' section of *La porte étroite* by André Gide.

> « Tout ce que vous demanderez à mon père en mon nom… »
>    Seigneur ! en votre nom je n’ose…
>    Mais si je ne formule plus ma prière, **en** connaîtrez-vous moins pour cela le délirant souhait de mon cœur ?

**QUESTION**

What is the contribution of *en* to the meaning of the sentence?

**BACKGROUND**

If *en* were not there, I might have tried to understand the sentence to mean:

> But if I no longer formulate my prayer, will you know (any the) less for that the delirious hope of my heart

where *pour cela* (*for that*) refers to the foregoing *si*-clause.

Alternatively, if *en* were there, but *pour cela* were gone this time, I might try to see in *en* a reference to the *si*-clause.

But with both *en* and *pour cela* there, I cannot be sure of the reference of either expression.

In Dorothy Bussy's translation, there is no express reference in the main clause to the *si*-clause.

> But though I no longer formulate my prayer, wilt Thou be the less aware of the delirious longing of my heart?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*En connaître*, according to the *TLFi*, means *être compétent pour juger*.

> − Spéc., DR., emploi intrans. [Le suj. désigne un juge et, p. ext.,
>   une assemblée délibérative] Connaître de qqc.; en connaître. Être
>   compétent pour juger.

(*TLFi*, [II, C, 2](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/conna%C3%AEtre))

So basically, *en* is part of this special and originally legalistic meaning of *connaître*.

And the general meaning of the sentence suddenly becomes apparent: if I no longer make the contents of my prayer known to you [*si je ne formule plus ma prière*], will you because of that be less competent in judging the delirious wish of my heart [*en connaîtrez-vous moins pour cela le délirant souhait de mon cœur*]?

Comment: Thank you. In that case, why wouldn't the sentence simply use the *Connaître de qqc* form? That would mean dropping the *en* and inserting *de* before *le délirant souhait*, (maybe) resulting in *du délirant souhait*. All told:  "Mais si je ne formule plus ma prière, connaîtrez-vous moins pour cela du délirant souhait de mon cœur". Would this be an alternative formulation?

Comment: Or maybe, should I think that, in Gide's original formulation, there is a relationship of apposition between *en* and *le délirant souhait de mon cœur*? I.e. a syntactic equivalent of: "Would you know of it any the less for that, the delirious hope of my heart?" where *it* and *hope* are apposite.

Comment: I think it's something like that. But French is a very sophisticated language, and French writers have always been equally sophisticated, if not even more so.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is just one of the many expressions where, to quote Grevisse (*Le Bon Usage*, 14th ed., §679) "*en* and *y* have an imprecise value", that is, they are pretty much impossible to analyze according to the  rules that normally apply to pronouns.

It's very hard to read this and not suffer from some "cross-contamination" from *n'en connaître pas moins*, "to know nonetheless". It could be just a variant of it (by suppression of *ne pas*, which doesn't change my conclusion above), but if it's a separate expression, I don't think I've ever run into it.

Answer (score 0):

Difference in meaning, which you can see in the translation:

1) Mais si je ne formule plus ma prière, **en** connaîtrez-vous **le délirant souhait de mon cœur** ? =

**will you know about [find out about] ** my heart's delirious wish?

Whereas:

2) Mais si je ne formule plus ma prière, connaîtrez-vous**  **le délirant souhait de mon cœur** ? =

**Will you know** my heart's delirious wish?

I simplified the sentence to make my point about the EN.

**One is to know something and the other is to know about something**.