# Pourquoi est-il correct d'utiliser « y » et « en » sans antécédents ?

Tags: grammaire, pronoms, antécédent, en

Pour expliciter l'antecédént de « en » en « en être », [ce fil de discussion](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/en-%C3%AAtre-en-rester-en-venir-valeur-impr%C3%A9cise-de-en.1841591/#post-14194916) cite *Le Bon usage* (2016), [§679](https://books.google.com/books?id=SX0wDQAAQBAJ&lpg=PA957&ots=U3XHmRR_v2&dq=%22En%20et%20y%20ont%20une%20valeur%20impr%C3%A9cise%20dans%20un%20grand%20nombre%20d'expressions%22&pg=PA957#v=onepage&q&f=true), para. a. Pourquoi les francophones acceptent-ils  cet usage des pronoms sans antécédents ? Cet usage me paraît erroné. A savoir, si un pronoun manque d'un antécédent ou une valeur imprécise, pourquoi la langue française n'exige-t-elle pas son explicitation ?

[image]

Comment: A good answer to this question would apply to many other ones we get.

Comment: Marrant, ça. J'étais certain que le fil en question était [celui-ci](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/25766/926) XD

Answer (score 5):

L'anaphore (c'est-à-dire la reprise d'un antécédent précédemment mentionné dans le discours) n'est pas une qualité nécessaire des pronoms, mais simplement un des rôles qu'ils remplissent fréquemment. Les pronoms personnels de la 1ère et de la 2ème personne en particulier sont rarement anaphoriques puisque les participants à une discussion sont tout le temps identifiables et "activés" dans le discours.

Deuxièmement, les pronoms personnels forment un continuum avec des affixes (généralement verbaux) qui marquent l'accord du verbe avec un de ses arguments ou qui servent à indiquer ou à modifier la valence d'un verbe. Les pronoms du français représentent un état intermédiaire dans ce continuum. Dans le cas de *en* et de *y*, c'est par leur capacité à modifier le sens d'un verbe ("Je me connais" et "je m'y connais" ou "je me moque de toi" et "je m'en moque de toi" ont un sens différent) que cette qualité intermédiaire ressort.

Puisque le pronom est d'usage plus applicatif qu'anaphorique dans ces expressions, il est inutile pour les locuteur du français de leur chercher un antécédent ou d'être perturbé par leur sens vague.

Finalement, des pronoms peuvent être *explétifs*, c'est-à-dire qu'ils ne se référent à rien du tout. On peut trouver des exemples avec la plupart des pronoms faibles du français:

> **Il** faut que tu partes
>
> Il se **la** pète
>
> Oufti, t'aurais dû voir comment elle **te** lui a dit ses quatre vérités, mec
>
> Il s'**y** croit
>
> Elle **en** veut (dans le sens d'avoir de l'ambition ou de la hargne)

Dans toutes ces phrases les pronoms en gras ne sont pas de réels arguments du verbes auxquels ils sont attachés, n'ont aucun antécédent et ne contribuent pas au sens du verbe *en tant que pronom*. Ça ne veut pas dire pour autant qu'ils soient inutiles puisqu'ils remplissent une case syntaxique qui doit être remplie pour que la phrase fonctionne, ou qu'ils modifient le sens du verbe du tout au tout. *Y* et *en* sont donc loin d'être exceptionnels sur ce point.

Answer (score 0):

Non natif mais je vais essayer quand même.

Tout d'abord les livres de grammaire du français que je possède n'en parlent pas.
J'ai cherché sur Internet et ai trouvé le lien ci-dessous :

http://theses.univ-lyon2.fr/documents/getpart.php?id=lyon2.2001.kim_bk&part=46818

D'autres prénoms relatifs peuvent s'employer sans antécédent :

> Qui a bu boira.

Concernant en et y leur usage peuvent être considérés idiomatiques dans une pléthore d'expressions (sans directe valeur grammaticale ; j'en pense:-)!).

http://www.espacefrancais.com/les-pronoms-personnels-en-et-y/

Quand l'on dit

> Il faut que je m'en aille

je crois que en n'est pas la fonction de pronom. C'est l'usage qui l'imposa.