# La fonction de « en » dans « en arriver là »

Tags: grammaire, pronoms, en

> *‘Enfant d’une secte, moi aussi, je me serais suicidée sur commande’.*
>
> Élevée dans une secte, Isabelle s’en est échappée à 28 ans. Elle
> dénonce à présent les pressions psychologiques et remâche son
> ‘enfance perdue’. À tel point qu’Isabelle affirme aujourd’hui
> ‘comprendre’ la folie des adeptes de l’ordre du Temple solaire:
>
> *‘J’ai
> réalisé que j’aurais aussi pu **en** arriver là. Si on me l’avait
> demandé, je me serais suicidée.*

(French Grammar in Context, p. 38. Extrait tiré d'Infomatin).

Quelle est la fonction de **en** dans **"...en arriver là."**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

« En arriver là » est une expression toute faite. *En* n'a pas d'antécédent. Cela arrive fréquemment en français, principalement pour *en* et *y*, comme dans « il y a », mais pas seulement. Voir [Pourquoi est-il correct d'utiliser « y » et « en » sans antécédents ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/29903/pourquoi-est-il-correct-dutiliser-y-et-en-sans-ant%c3%a9c%c3%a9dents) pour une description plus générale du phénomène.

Comment: Merci pour cette réponse. Au fait, j'avais essayé de donner une réponse à la question dont vous parlez. Les deux réponses que j'ai reçues se contredisent, n'est-ce pas ? L'une parle du pronom, l'autre d'un usage idiomatique. Étant non natif je ne sais laquelle choisir:-)!

Answer (score 2):

C'est un pronom complément. Elle aurait pu arriver au fait de se suicider comme les autres personnes.

[Emploi du pronom complément neutre « en » (Wikipedia)](https://www.wikiwand.com/fr/Syntaxe_du_pronom_personnel_en_fran%C3%A7ais#/Emploi_du_pronom_compl%C3%A9ment_neutre_%C2%AB_en_%C2%BB)

Comment: Merci. Ce pronom en, il remplace quoi ici ?

Comment: C'est bon. Merci encore !

Comment: Avec plaisir @dimitris !